# Get Picture from Worksheet into Excel Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to view an image from the worksheet in an Image control on a userform.

This image will change based on the value on a combobox. I have inserted (Using: Insert -> Pictures) a couple of images into "Sheet1" of my workbook and named them "Picture1" & "Picture2".

I have created the below UserForm:

[Form http://im56.gulfup.com/msKyqi.png](http://im56.gulfup.com/msKyqi.png)

And this is the code that I am trying to use in order to load the images from the sheet, but unfortunately, this is not working at the moment.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(ComboBox1.Value))

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

UserForm1.ComboBox1.Clear
UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Picture1"
UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Picture2"

UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "Picture1"

UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(ComboBox1.Value))

End Sub
```

Every time I run this code I get the below error:

[Error http://im43.gulfup.com/YoWvTp.png](http://im43.gulfup.com/YoWvTp.png)

Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out!

As I am using a UserForm there is a workaround to the issue.

Instead of having the images in the worksheet to then try and load them in the form I tried having them in the UserForm in the first place, here is how.

Create a frame on your userform:
[Frame http://im88.gulfup.com/Moy8I6.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/Moy8I6.png)

Set the visible property of the frame to "**False**":
[Visible http://im88.gulfup.com/sAIQqh.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/sAIQqh.png)

Insert your images by adding a picture control and loading the images, you can add as many images as you need:
[Images http://im88.gulfup.com/oas0EQ.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/oas0EQ.png)

Name the images:
[Name http://im88.gulfup.com/cIO317.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/cIO317.png)

Drag all the images one over the other into the frame, (you can then move the frame into a corner so it doesn't bother you:

[Drag http://im88.gulfup.com/1fOSut.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/1fOSut.png)
[Move Away http://im88.gulfup.com/Q1fzKd.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/Q1fzKd.png)

Next create a picture control, this is what you will use to display the picture based on a selection:

[Form View http://im88.gulfup.com/X1UVRB.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/X1UVRB.png)

In this example, I am going to use a combobox for the selection. Now insert the below code in to the form which is pretty straight forward:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    ' Image1 is the name of the created picture control
    UserForm3.Controls.Item("Image1").Picture = UserForm3.Controls.Item(UserForm3.ComboBox1.Value).Picture 

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    UserForm3.ComboBox1.AddItem "Argentina"
    UserForm3.ComboBox1.AddItem "Brazil"
    UserForm3.ComboBox1.AddItem "Chile"

    End Sub
```

As you will see, the frame with the pictures is Hidden, and the image is changing inside the picture control based on a selection:

[Result http://im88.gulfup.com/MSqyHF.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/MSqyHF.png)

I think it's the better way to go as opposed to exporting the images from the worksheet to  a Temp folder and then loading them back into the picture controls.

Comment: Wouldn't this increase file size by loading your image twice? (once in the worksheet and a second time into your userform)

Comment: @JohnsonJason there are no images in the worksheet, they are in a hidden picture control on the userform. You may read the answer again.

Comment: I understand that your answer involves images only in the form in order to enable the dynamic form image switch. However, I have images in a worksheet as the original question stated. I can't move them out of the worksheet as they are part of the interface. I would like these images to ALSO be in the form. So using your solution I would have images twice.

Comment: @JohnsonJason In this case yes :(. But this was the only solution that I could come up with since excel userforms don't read images directly from the worksheet without perhaps a lot of extra code.

Comment: @JohnsonJason - How large are the pictures? If they are large, perhaps you can optimize their size, that is, use a good image editor to make them the size you need in the worksheet or userform without having to shrink them in the worksheet or userform.

Answer (score 3):

The LoadImage() function expects a filename (which can be fully qualified with a drive letter and path). You are getting a type mismatch because it wants a string, and you are giving it an image object.

There is, as far as I know, no simple way to put an image that resides in the current application into an image control.  The (hackish) workaround that I know about is to export the image to a file, and then import that same file using LoadImage().

This is the same path you have to go down if you want to embed a chart that updates dynamically into a userform.  You export the chart as an image (e.g., a JPEG), and then use LoadImage() to pull the image back into the image control.

Comment: It's `LoadPicture()`, not `LoadImage()`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is ancient, but I found my way here. I came up with a slightly different solution to this problem. I have about 30 pictures I need to load based on a combo-box selection. First, all combo-box options (for discussion "XX") are saved to a separate worksheet which is "Very hidden" from the user and loaded into the combobox on userform activation. On the userform a frame was added, and within the frame 30 image-boxes all overlapping perfectly were placed. Each image-box was carefully named "Img_XX" where XX is the simple two-letter identifier.

With this setup it is now possible to iterate through each "Control" (the image boxes) in the Frame and hide them all, except the one with a name that matches the combo-box value. The code in the userform module, within the Combobox_Change() function, looks something like this:

```
 Private Sub ComboBox_Change()
    Dim SearchValue as String
    SearchValue = me.Combobox.value

    Dim Ctrl as Control
    For each Ctrl in Me.TestFrame.Controls
        If Ctrl.Name Like "img_" & SearchValue Then
            Ctrl.visible = True
        else
            Ctrl.Visible = False
        End If
    next Ctrl
 End Sub
```

I hope this helps, let me know what you think. :)